# Strange Behavior with clamd scan function

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server, clamav

I have a simple python3 script running on ubuntu server 20.04 that tries to call clamd (clamav-daemon process) library to scan a file.  The scan ping() and version() function all work correctly.  However when I actually do a test write and scan, i get the following error:

```
{'/filedrop/test.doc': ('ERROR', "Can't open file or directory")}
```

This is the code that I used to call the test write and scan, and this is all standard sample from the clamd website:

```
open('/filedrop/test.doc','wb').write(clamd.EICAR)
print(cd.scan('/filedrop/test.doc'))
```

After the code is run, i get the following string in the test file which indicates that the python3 script was able to successfully write to the file, yet i keep getting the error that the file can't be opened when i use the clamd scan function.

This is the string that was written to the file:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

I am also able to run clamscan from command line on the folder and it successfully scans the files as well.

I'm running as root user while the service is using clamav:clamav.
I did give read/write permission to the folder and the files to "other users", and also indicated by the fact that the file could be written by the python script.

Comment: Did you give execute permission to the folder to other users?

Comment: i did.  The permission is available for all users.  one strange behavior i see is that I can't seem to change the "ownership" of those files but other processes should still be able to modify/execute.

Comment: Be good to see the output of:
ls -lt / | grep filedrop;
ls -lt /filedrop/;  

You may even be falling fail of something like AppArmour https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor

Comment: drwxrwxrwx   2 clamav clamav       4096 Mar 24 17:03 filedrop
total 8
-rw-rw-rw- 1 clamav clamav  68 Mar 24 16:44 test.doc
-rw-rw-rw- 1 clamav clamav 692 Mar 24 16:29 autoscan.py

Comment: grep audit /var/log/kern.log
or if it exists:
grep DENIED /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: i have stopped the apparmor service via sudo systemctl stop apparmor, but still having same issue with the python script

Comment: and I think you still need to disable it also with: sudo systemctl disable apparmor

Comment: i saw this in the audit log: kernel: [108386.130893] audit: type=1400 audit(1616605697.875:129): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/clamd" name="/filedrop/test.doc" pid=53749 comm="clamd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=123 ouid=123

Comment: does this indicate it was apparmor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution to the problem here is that AppArmour is blocking clamd for that particular directory.  I would look at the AppArmour profile for clamd. It should be called something like /etc/apparmor.d/clamav or similar.  You can adjust that profile or alternatively disable it (according to Ubuntu):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/profile.name /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/profile.name
```

More complete instructions available here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor

You can also disable AppArmour, for the purposes of testing (I don't like to advise anyone to remove security features permanently), with:

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor
sudo systemctl disable apparmor
```

Comment: woohoo, disabling didn't work at first but after restart it worked! Thank you so much! i would have never thought of this in a million years.